# Sticky table header on page scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code pen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/EEBPKo

The table header is sticky when scrolling, its not perfect but a starting point.

I need this to work in a page with content above the table.

I have another code pen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/jzjbpO

Is it possible to adapt this javascript so the table header is sticky when it reaches the page top and the table content scrolls

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  var thead = this.querySelectorAll("thead");
  for (var i = 0; i < thead.length; i++) {
    thead[i].style.transform=translate;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle thead css position when your table scrollTop position is null or negative then :

```
thead.sticky{ position: fixed; top: 0; }
```

Then you have to adjust `thead.left` position, and each `thead ths` width so it correspond to each `tbody tds`.

Comment: How would I do that with the Javascript I have